# Yii2 Pjax reloads entire page

Tags: javascript, php, yii2, pjax

Is there someone who can help me with the following?
I use a modal/form to edit a model onscreen, and update the model via Pjax. Saving is no problem, but now the gridview must be updated with Pjax as well.

For my modal I use the following code

```
<?php 
$form = ActiveForm::begin(
    ['enableClientValidation' => true, 'options' => ['id' => $model->formName()]]);
?>

<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title"><?= $actionTitle ?> <?= StringHelper::basename(get_class($model)); ?></h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    ...
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <?php echo Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end();

$this->registerJs(<<<JS
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $(e.target).removeData('bs.modal');
    });
JS
);

?>

<?php $script = <<< JS

$('form#{$model->formName()}').on('beforeSubmit', function(e){
    var \$form = $(this);
    $.post(
        \$form.attr("action"), //Serialize Yii2 Form
        \$form.serialize()
    ).done(function(result){
        if(result == true){
            $(\$form).trigger("reset");
            $(document).find('#modalphysicalcomponent').modal('hide');
            $.pjax.defaults.timeout = false;
            $.pjax.reload({container:'#Grid'});
        }else{
            $("#message").html(result.message);
        }
    }).fail(function(){
        console.log("server error");
    });

    return false;

});

JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

It should update only the following gridview, but instead reloads the entire page which results in an error as certain POST variables are not resend.

```
<?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'Grid']); ?>
        <?= GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'columns' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
                'id',
                'component.tag',
                'component.name',
                'component.parent.tag',
                [
                    'label' => 'Configure',
                    'format'=>'raw',
                    'value' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column){
                        return Html::a('Configure '.get_class($model), ['update-modal', 'id' => $model->component->id], ['data-toggle'=>'modal', 'data-target'=>'#modalphysicalcomponent' ,'class' => 'btn btn-xs btn-primary', ]);
                    }
                ],
            ],
        ]); ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

I use the same modal on a different page, and it seems to work fine there, but I can't spot any differences between the two view pages.

Anyone who can help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the grid id as text, and not object when reloading the gridview. The object is passed as the second parameter which are the options.

This is your mistake

```
$.pjax.reload({container:'#Grid'});`
```

it should be like below

```
$.pjax.reload('#Grid');
```

See the docs for the Pjax [here](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax#pjaxreload)

Comment: This does not fix the issue, but also does not break the other page, so it seems fine to me. I think the problem must be somewhere else, as it looks like the Yii action is recalled when the grid is refreshed. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @nick4sure not getting exactly what you are saying here, using the above suggestion did not solve the actual problem that is reloading of the specific div you are asking for ?

Comment: No it did not fix my problem, but because of that, I think there is something else going on. when I try to reload the grid, it seems like Yii is "recalling" the action which displays the view. But Since some POST values are not available anymore, it can't reconstruct the page. (Plus I don't want to, as I create a bunch of database records before rendering the view) What code is helpful to show you?